# PlayBasis not registering users, getting message='User doesn't exist'

Tags: android

I'm trying to register users on my PlayBasis App using the Android SDK. However, it's not registering them.

The method

```
PlayerApi.register onSuccess()
```

is being called but the users never get registered. They don't show on the dashboard and when I try to get them I receive

```
RequestError{message='User doesn't exist', errorCode=200}
```

Can you recommend any other gamification platform that offer low price for small/indie apps?

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated the case and found that 
you actually can registered 7 players into our system on 24 September. 
And this would also explain why Android SDK fires onSuccess().

However, it is like the problem is that you cannot find those players. 
Just want to verify with you first that for getting detail of player, 
you should supply "player_id", NOT "username".

Lastly, on "User" menu on the dashboard, you are going to find 
only the list of dashboard users, NOT the list of players.

Best Regards, 
Thanakij